# Не совсем правильно работает команда time-out Discord.py Disnake.py

Tags: python, бот, discord.py, discord, disnake

Я сделал команду мьют и добавил туда строчку кода

1. `time=time.replace('час', 'h').replace('мин', 'm').replace('сек', 's')`

2)`time=time.replace('h', 'час').replace('m', 'мин').replace('s', 'сек')`

Первая версия это тест версия и она идеально работает ее правильное использование ">мьют @username 10сек нарушил" единственное что мне не нравиться что вывод у бота такой "✅ Учасник @username замучен на 10s" и я считаю это не правильным ведь я делаю полностью бота на русском языке. Нужно чтобы было не "s" а "сек"

Вторая версия идельно исправляет эту ошибку но есть 1 но в первой версии мы пишем "10сек" а в этой версии ругается что нужен пробел то есть "10 сек" нужно сделать как в 1 версии. Еще когда происходит мьют бот пишет человеку не правильное сообщение.

В общем все должно работать как в первом случае но время должно быть на русском языке а не на английском. Заранее большое спасибо!

```
@bot.command(aliases=["Мьют"])
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def мьют(ctx, member: disnake.Member, time=None, *, reason=None):
    if member != None:
        if time != None:
            time=time.replace('h', 'час').replace('m', 'мин').replace('s', 'сек')
            t = humanfriendly.parse_timespan(time)
            await member.timeout(until = disnake.utils.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=t), reason=reason)
            if reason != None:
                embed = disnake.Embed(
                    description = f'✅ Учасник {member.mention} успешно замучен на {time} {reason}',
                    color=0xc80005)
                await member.send(f"Модератор {ctx.author.mention} замьютил Вас на сервере **{ctx.guild.name}** на {time} по причине: {reason}.")
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            else:
                embed = disnake.Embed(
                    description = f'**✅ Учасник {member.mention}** замучен на {time}',
                    color=0xc80005)
                await member.send(f"Модератор {ctx.author.mention} замьютил Вас на сервере **{ctx.guild.name}** на {time}.")
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            embed = disnake.Embed(
                description = f'❌ {ctx.author}  укажите  время  наказания',
                color=0xc80005)        
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        embed = disnake.Embed(
            description = f'❌ {ctx.author}  укажите  кого  нужно  наказать',
            color=0xc80005)        
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Вот картинка вывода
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы неправильно меня поняли. Нужно добавить вторую строчку не вместо первой, а перед выводом

Comment: Команда теперь правильно работает огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить вторую строчку не вместо первой, а перед выводом. Тогда у вас всё заработает.